Azure Granted Permission to SQL Server not authenticating
I have granted an Azure user within our organization with SQL Contributor access to our SQL database:

But when the user attempts access the database from Azure's Query editor, they get the message

Login failed for user


Can someone let me know if there are any additional permissions that I need to grant the user?

Azure SQL has its own users, roles, and permissions inside it. Assigning a role from Azure Portal with Azure's RBAC won't give the user rights to connect to the database.
You must instead connect to the database with an Entra ID (Azure AD) user and run e.g.:
CREATE USER [test.user@example.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','test.user@example.com';

This would create the user and grant them read access to everything. You should consider what access they need.

Role granted through Azure Portal -> Management access to Azure resource, edit settings, view metrics etc.
Role/permissions granted through SQL -> Connect, run queries

If the user only needs to connect and run queries, you don't need the Azure RBAC role.

I just want to give users read access - nothing beyond that. However, your answer suggests users will have access to everything. Correct

Hi @Juunas, when I execute your suggestion, I get the following error Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 2 Could not find stored procedure 'u'.

You can check built-in SQL roles here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-database-roles. The db_datareader role in my example grants read access to all tables and views. You can also go more specific with GRANT statements to give read access to specific tables etc.

Hmm not sure about that error. Maybe something odd about the quotes?

I got it. I needed to be logged in with an Active Directory Account to assign someone with an Activie Directory Account. Your suggestion worked. Thank you

Ah, good point. Should have mentioned that.
